# Pure inductor with ideal battery

Tags: electric-circuits

If we connect battery having EMF E with pure inductor and assumes No resistance. Back EMF induced is Ldi/dt but how can we say that the term di/dt multiply by L will be equal to battery EMF . Books explain it with help of kirchoff law . So explain without kirchoff law.

Answer (score 0):

It is the obvious limit when resistance of the circuit goes to zero.

For a circuit with total resistance $R$, Kirchhoff's second circuital law states

$$
\mathscr{E}_{bat} + \mathscr{E}_{ind} = RI.
$$
In this "realistic" case, the battery emf magnitude does not equal the induced emf magnitude.

Now take the limit $R\to 0$. Current has to stay finite because infinite current would mean infinite energy in the inductor, which is not realistic. So in the limit $R=0$, we obtain

$$
\mathscr{E}_{bat} + \mathscr{E}_{ind} = 0.
$$

Induced emf of inductor is always

$$
\mathscr{E}_{ind} = -L\frac{dI}{dt}
$$
so we get the equation the current has to obey, given the battery emf:

$$
\mathscr{E}_{bat} = L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$